# Executing bash echo and nc together in golang

Tags: bash, go, exec

This is probably a simple problem. Working on a linux machine and I'm trying to send a command to the shell from a `go` program.  I have a server listening for requests.  This line of code is giving me problems though.

```
cmd := exec.Command("echo -n 'hello' | nc localhost 3333")
```

The rest of my code runs the command properly...

However it's just recognizing it as an echo argument with the *rest being part of the string it's echoing*.  I want to pipe the echo to `nc` to send the message to server.

I have tried rearranging it, such as in this manner:

```
cmd := exec.Command("echo", "-n", "'hello' | nc localhost 3333")
```

But they produce the same result, or an error:

`executable file not found $PATH`

How do I execute echo and a piped command like nc together in this manner from a go script.

Comment: Pipes are shell syntax, which is unlikely to be available when running commands from other languages. There is probably a way to pass something on standard input to a `Command`.

Comment: Duplicate. You'll find lots of similar questions here.

Comment: There is no reason to execute echo with a static argument. Just assign a strings.Reader to [Command.Stdin](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd), for instance.

Answer (score 2):

`|`, `>`, `<`, `&`,`...`,`cd`,`...` and many more were shell builtins, these were interpreted by `shell` and executed accordingly.

So you need to call `shell`, and execute your command with `-c` flag, mentioning `shell` to execute the following argument as a command.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    sh := os.Getenv("SHELL") //fetch default shell
    //execute the needed command with `-c` flag
    cmd := exec.Command(sh, "-c ", `echo -n 'hello' | grep "h"`)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()
}
```

Here I was using `grep`, because I don't have `nc`